# How to show and hide PImages depending on framerate?

Tags: image, processing, animated-gif

I am a first-year uni student learning Processing and I am having some trouble :(

I want to create the illusion of waves in my program (I am creating an interactive story) and I intend to do this by making a continuous gif.

So far I have loaded images of the wave at each point in the animation in an array of PImages and have created 'if' statements to show them in succession.

How do I make it so that after one image is shown it is hidden as the next one is shown? Currently they are simply layering over one another.

I will paste my code down below,
Thanks for the help!

```
PImage [] waves = new PImage[3];
void setup() {
    size(750, 600);
    background(#A3E9EA);
    waves[0] = loadImage("wave1.png");
    waves[1] = loadImage("wave2.png");
    waves[2] = loadImage("wave3.png");
    frameRate(5);
}

void draw() {
    frameCount++;
    println (frameCount);
    if (frameCount < 5) {
        image(waves[0], 0, 0);
    } else {
        image(waves[1], 0, 0);
    }
    if (frameCount < 15 & frameCount > 10) {
        image(waves[2], 0, 0);
        frameCount = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: the simplest solution would be to redraw the background as a first action in draw. This override the old waves.

Comment: Thank you! That worked :) I feel so dumb ahaha